# nodeJS + MSSQL, connection to db error: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js

let's first see the code before I start talking:

```
var sqlDb = require("mssql");
var settings = require("../settings"); 

exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) { 


var conn = new sqlDb.Connection(settings.dbConfig);
console.log('db.js Send sql-query');
console.log(" ");
conn.connect()              
.then(function () {        
    var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
    req.query(sql)              
    .then(function (recordset) {
        callback(recordset);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("here it breaks", err);       
        callback(null, err);    //type error: undefined is not a function
    })
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);       
    callback(null, err);    
});  //
};
```

This function recieves an sql statement and a callback function. When I run the code I get [Type Error: undefined is not a function].

When I comment out the callback(recordset) it doesnt do anything (no error but also nothing else). So I think that the callback is simply not recognized as if it were out of scope. The weird part is, that the error object is transferred back via the same callback function and that seems to work.

The settings.dbConfig looks like this:

```
exports.dbConfig = {
user: "username",
password: "pwd",
server: "SERVERNAME",  // not localhost
database: "DB-Name",
port: 1433 
};
```

I am quite depressed by now. Would someone be so kind as to have a look at my code? I simply don't see the mistake.

Thank you

EDIT: 
I call executeSql like this:

```
var db = require("./db");
var sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";

db.executeSql(sql, function(data, err) { 
if (err) {
  console.log(" Internal Error: error connecting Database", err);
} else {
  console.log("success", data);
}
```

});

Comment: for some reason the first line of my post is missing. it should say "Hello everyone"

Comment: I would like to suggest for you to use Sequelize: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/ - let see the docs. It's a good ORM.

Comment: How are you calling `executeSql`? Are you passing a function object?

Comment: Yes, I do. I put it in the edit above. Does that help?

Comment: Where is the error thrown exactly? On the `callback(recordset);` line? Log `callback` at the start of the function and just before that line to check whether it's actually valid. If the error is thrown somewhere else, please let us know where.